# Is Aurelia a viable choice for production applications?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, reactjs, angular, aurelia

We need to migrate our WPF application to web and I'm comparing the Aurelia framework with various other frameworks (including Angular 1, Angular 2, and React). We need to release it within 6-7 months.

Though I've read numerous articles that favor Aurelia over other frameworks, I'm concerned whether Aurelia is ready for production development. Aurelia is currently still in beta, so I'm worried about breaking changes. Also, the buzz is [mostly around the other frameworks mentioned above][1], and so I'm worried about Aurelia becoming unsupported or Aurelia developers becoming difficult to find. Is Aurelia a viable choice for production applications?

[1]: https://web.archive.org/web/20170217030131/https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=aurelia js, react js, angular 2&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT-1

Comment: Downvote propably because your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You could easily write a book about this question ;)

Answer (score 5):

This question will be closed because it is primarily opinion based, and that's no good. However, you've asked a very good question in there that I'd like to answer in the mean time: Is it dangerous to build a long term supported production app in Aurelia?

First, there's the fact that it is in beta. [RC is coming soon](http://blog.durandal.io/2016/04/13/aurelia-mid-april-2016-patch-update/), so I wouldn't worry about the tag. But then, you must also consider one man's beta is another man's 1.0. Take a look at out [pre-beta release notes](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/11/10/aurelia-pre-beta-release/) to see the main breaking changes we experienced in moving from alpha to beta. Conversely, it seems the Angular 2 router was recently [fully rewritten right for RC](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3065233/javascript/angularjs-2-reaches-beta.html) with [lots of issues](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+created%3A%3E2016-05-03+router). All this to say, Aurelia takes these terms as seriously as possible, when others may not, and you can put your confidence in that.

Another question is trending. The main reason for this is the names behind the products. There is little a small team can do to pull in the same kind of buzz that Google (Angular) or Facebook (React) can. We don't have an official developer conference that pulls in that kind of crowd yet. However, not all buzz is good buzz. React has been [officially credited](https://medium.com/@ericclemmons/javascript-fatigue-48d4011b6fc4#.6z49j8k0s) with spawning the #jsfatigue trend earlier this year. As you mentioned in your first paragraph, the buzz around Aurelia, though not as loud as React, is very positive.

My primarily opinion based answer is a big thumbs up for Aurelia, and I hope I've put some of your concerns to rest.

If my avatar didn't give it away, I am an [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) team member.